# How to add a className to an element inside a variable in react?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, web, frontend

I want to add some classes to an element dynamically. I know how to do it with `html-dom` and how to do it with passing a javascript expression to `className`. But these are not what I want to do. I am wondering if there is a way to add it like `push`ing that class to an array or concatenating it to a string in that component object.

---

It is a pseudo-code of what I'm looking for:

```js
const el = <div className='one' />;
// Notice that I'm not using useRef hook.
el.classList.push('two');

// OR:
el.className += ' two';
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Typically, you will do this by calculating the class name before you create the JSX element:

```
let className = "one";
className += " two";
const el = <div className={className} />
```

If that's not possible (say, you received this element as a prop from a parent, and so it has a classname of "one" already baked in), then you would need to use cloneElement:

```
import { cloneElement } from 'react';

const el = <div className='one' />;
const newElement = cloneElement(el, { className: el.props.className + " two "});
```

Comment: Isn't there a simpler way than `cloneElement`? If not, this is what I'm looking for.

Comment: What you're doing is rarely needed. JSX elements are not really meant to be modified after they're created. Since it's rarely needed, they havn't made a simpler way to do it.

Answer (score 0):

You should try having one array variable with your different classes where you can push conditionally the classes your need and in your jsx split the array.

Like this:

```js
const classNames = ['one']
classNames.push('two');

const el = <div className={classNames.split(' ')} />;
```

Your element isn't a node element where you have a classList property and you can add and remove classes. It is a JSX element. Even if it ressembles an html element in its structure.

Comment: This is not what I'm looking for. I don't want to pass an expression to `classList`. element should be created before adding class.

Comment: Your element isn't a node element where you have a classList property and you can add and remove classes. It is a JSX element. Even if it ressembles a html element in its structure.

Comment: I'd like to point out that arrays don't have a `split` method. In any case, since the `className` attribute takes a space-separated list of class names, did you by aby chance mean `classNames.join(' ')`?